# Overriding save() on many-to-many fields with a 'through' field

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

With the code below, when performing `set_instance.items.add()` how can I have SetMeta.order to default to `len(set.items.all())`

I've tried over riding save() on SetMeta but save doesn't get called when performing add(). Also tried signals with SetMeta as the sender, but SetMeta sends a Set instance rather than a SetMeta instance. Seems like it should be simple but I can't figure it out.

Ultimately, every `item` within a `set` should have an `order` equal to `len(set_instance.items.all()`

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model, AdminVideoMixin):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    **** LOTS OF OTHER FIELDS ****


class Set(Item):
    front_page = models.BooleanField(max_length=300, blank=False, default=False, null=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='in_sets', through='SetMeta', max_length=5000,)


class SetMeta(models.Model):

    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='itemOrder', max_length=5000, )
    set = models.ForeignKey(Set, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='setOrder', max_length=5000,)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True,)
```

UPDATE. Could also set `order` to set.items.count()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), you can use either of these solutions:

**One**, use the `through` Model:

```
item = Item.objects.first()
set = Set.objects.first()
icount = set.items.count() + 1
SetItem.objects.create(item=item, set=set, order=icount)
```

**Two**, use `through_defaults`:

```
item = Item.objects.first()
set = Set.objects.first()
icount = set.items.count() + 1
set.items.add(item, through_defaults={'order':icount})
```

FYI,(as per your Update section), for your case, you don't need to store the order in through model. You can add a property method to see the data:

```
class SetMeta(models.Model):
   ...
   @property
   def order(self):
     return self.set.items.count()
```

Comment: That sounds interesting - what does that give me then?

Comment: How can I make use of that?

Comment: Ahh - I understand now. I need the order, so I can update it with up() and down() methods defined on SetMeta. I order the Set class with it. With your method, using through_defaults, there's no way to do this in signals or on the model itself? I have to now create all models through a 'through' class in order to get this 'order' functionality?

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear what you are asking by `With your method, using through_defaults, there's no way to do this in signals or on the model itself?` can you please give some examples?

Comment: I didn't want to have to change the way I use set.items.add() - I want my order attribute to always default to set.items.count(). 

With your help I have now achieved this with a post save signal. I set a method on my SetMeta class called default_order() which simply sets self.order to self.set.items.count(). I call that function on new items being added via an m2m_changed signal.